# Adding a namespace based element to an existing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How would I append `<meta>` element programatically to an existing XML file using XDocument

```
<Test xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:kishore="http://www.sample.com">
<meta>
    <kishore:params kishore:version="1.0">
        <kishore:textContent kishore:styleProp="TextProp" kishore:replaceID="Te"/>
    </kishore:params>
</meta>
</Test>
```

Comment: is this your initial xml or desired? Give any if absent.

Comment: it has many other elements in it. I would like to add <meta> tag as its first child. That is child of <Test> root node

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    var doc = new XDocument();
    var root = new XElement(XName.Get("Test"));
    var meta = new XElement(XName.Get("meta"));
    root.Add(meta);
    doc.Add(root);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```